# Socket.IO disconnect in appdelegate

Tags: objective-c, socket.io

I'm trying to shutdown all my [socket](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) connections when the app moves to the background. The same goes for returning to the main tableview. I can't really figure out why I can reach the right socket object in my viewDidDissappear and disconnect the socket like so:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [_socketIO disconnect];
}
```

But when I try to make my own disconnect method and call that method in my appdelegate (applicationDidEnterBackground) the right socket connection can't be found. There are no errors but the socket won't disconnect properly (I still see data coming in if I look in to my server logs).

My appdelegate.m part is as following:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DetailViewController* detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    [detailViewController disconnectSocket];    
}
```

And my detailViewController disconnectSocket method like this:

```
- (void) disconnectSocket
{    
    [_socketIO disconnectForced];
}
```

It's probably something stupid I'm overlooking but I'm kind of stuck here. The idea is to exit the socket connection when the app goes to the background and when the app enters the foreground again it reconnects.

Comment: What class is `_socketIO`?

Comment: I delegate my detailViewController.h to SocketIODelegate and call it in my viewDidLoad like this:

        _socketIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

Comment: I'd like to know *what* `_socketIO` *is*.  If it's a third-party class, then please provide a link (actually even if Apple supply it, please provide a link).

Comment: Sorry, kind of a noob on this stuff. It's part of the https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc <- library.

Comment: OK.  Was the data you see at the server in-transit before you closed the socket or are you saying data is still being written over the socket, even though you've closed it?

Comment: It's still being written. If I close the socket with the viewDidDisappear the server says 'discarding transport', so that says it actually closes the connection. When I try it in my disconnectSocket it keeps sending info.

Comment: I figured out another way. My instance to the detailViewController wasn't right so the socket it wanted to disconnect was referenced to another object. 

I registered a notification (applicationDidEnterBackground) in my detailViewController and closed my socket there.